# postgresql update query containes select query

Tags: postgresql

I want to update the content of a table calls VIDEO_TAGS which contains 3 columns, fk_video_id, principal (not too important), and tag_value.

I want to do an update as follows,

```
"UPDATE VIDEO_TAGS 
SET tag_value= :newTag 
where tag_value= :oldTag 
  and fk_video_id = (SELECT FROM VIDEO_TAGS fk_video_id where tag_value= :productName)"
```

but it is clear that the sub-query will return many elements, while I only need one element -more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression ERROR-.
my question is how to edit the sub-query to get the one element that I need? Thank you

Comment: I suggest to start by adding `video_id` to `(SELECT FROM VIDEO_TAGS`, and use `(SELECT video_id FROM VIDEO_TAGS`   (or at least the field that has the id for the video you are looking for)

Comment: To get max 1 row from a sub-query, you can use [LIMIT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-limit.html). But that also needs an ORDER BY, see [Postgres LIMIT/OFFSET strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644631/postgres-limit-offset-strange-behaviour)

Comment: If multiple videos have the same productName, how do ***you*** want to choose just one? The first, the last, which one? *(It sounds more likely that you need to update **all** of those videos? If so, use `fk_video_id IN (sub-query)` instead.)*